# Angle between edge and face of pyramid

Tags: trigonometry

A pyramid has a horizontal square base ABCD of side 2a. Its vertex V is vertically above the centre O of the base, and the length of VO is 2a. The line through V perpendicular to the face VAD meets the plane of the base at X.

Find

(i) the length of VX

(ii) the cosine of the angle between the faces VAB and VAD

(iii) the sine of the angle between the edge VC and the face VAB.

I have done parts (i) and (ii)  but cannot do (iii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Q is the midpoint of AB and VP is perpendicular to the face VAB meeting the extension of QO at P. Due to the similar triangles VQO and VOP, we have OP = 4. Also,

$$VC^2 = VO^2 + OC^2 = 6,\>\>\>\>\>VP^2 = VO^2+OP^2 = 20$$

$$CP^2= OC^2+OP^2-2\cdot OC\cdot OP\cos45=10$$

Then, apply the cosine rule to the triangle VCP,

$$CP^2 = VC^2+VP^2-2\cdot VC\cdot VP\cos\theta$$

and substitute the lengths calculated above to obtain,

$$\cos\theta = \frac{6+20-10}{2\sqrt6 \cdot \sqrt{20}} = \frac4{\sqrt{30}}$$

which is also the sine of the angle between the edge VC and the face VAB since VP is perpendicular to the face.

Comment: In your last sentence, do you not mean VP is perpendicular to the face?

Comment: @SteveHarris - Thanks for catching it. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let the vertexes be $V(0,0,2)$ and $C(-1,1,0)$, The normal vector to the face $VAB$ is $\vec{n}=(2,0,1)$. Then, 
$$\cos\theta = \frac{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{CV}}{|\vec{n}||\vec{CV}|}
=\frac{(2,0,1)\cdot(1,-1,2)}{\sqrt5\cdot\sqrt6}=\frac4{\sqrt{30}}$$

which is also the sine of the angle between the edge $VC$ and the face $VAB$ since $\vec{n}$ is perpendicular to the face..

Comment: @SteveHarris - It is possible to just rely on trig approach, which I put out as another answer. It is a bit more involved that the coordinates. I don't use MathsJax, just a simple drawing tool for lines and shapes, etc.